# id mapping of NFS does not work for all directories

Tags: permissions, nfs

I have an NFS server/client setup. On both server and client, the user `me` exists and has the same UID. If I mount the `/home` directory from the NFS server on the client, I see that `nobody` owns the folder `/home/me/` on the client. However, all files within `/home/me/*` are correctly shown as owned by `me`.

On the NFS server, `/home/me` and all files and folders within are owned by `me`.

Why am I seeing this root directory as `nobody` while all other directories work as expected?

Comment: Is  this NFSv4? Mentions of UID/GID issues in this howto: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NFSv4Howto

Comment: It is NFSv4. I'll check out the debugging stuff, thank you!